# How to convert SQL statement to Power BI DAX?

Tags: mysql, sql, powerbi

I have no idea how to recreate the following code from SQL to DAX in Power BI:

```
select Z, sum(X) as sumcount, avg(Y) as avgcount
from example_table
group by Z
```

Or perhaps there is a way to operate on SQL commands in Power BI with imported and filtered tables?

I want to do the SQL query on the already sliced data in Power BI.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by following dax calculated table

```
Table = summarize(example_table[z], "sumcount", sum(example_table[x]), " Avgcount", Average(example_table[Y]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute sql queries from direct query feature, where connect data host and schema.

[image]

Comment: Yes, yes I know. However, then I do not actually execute the SQL query on the filtered table that has already been pulled by the PowerBI. At least as far as I am concerned. Thank very much you for the reply, though.

Answer (score 0):

**how to create the code from SQL to DAX in Power BI as:**

```
Select
   History.[Key],
   History.[Issue Type],
   History.[Current Status],
   SUM(History.[Time in Old Value (business days)]) as 'Blocked Time'
FROM History
INNER JOIN CYCLOTIME
   ON HISTORY.[KEY] = CYCLOTIME.[KEY]
   AND HISTORY.[History Start] >= CycloTime.[Dt Inicio]
Where 
   History[History Field] = "flagged"
and
   History[History Old Value] = "Impedimento"
GROUP BY
   History.[Key],
   History.[Issue Type],
   History.[Current Status]
```